# Principal get user ID

Tags: java, spring-websocket

I can’t get a user other than his name but the name is not uniquely needed by id or full user
I have

```
@Component
public class WebSocketEventListener {
    private static final Logger logger = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketEventListener.class);

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
        logger.info("Received a new web socket connection");

        System.out.println("User connection : " + event.getUser());
    }
}
```

There is a method getUser() getName but the name is not uniquely,
and  method event.getUser() gives something terrible)) --

```
User connection : 
org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fe260c00: Principal: 
User(id=1, username=admin, password=$2a$08$VDogbqVQY23gNnLFty/6ReGLecW/bk3oCkUHrsly4HgjBIGRNBSEC, 
email=kiy9@gmail.com); Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3566D00689DCC01041367983F3132937; Granted Authorities: USER
```

Is there any way to get a User from there or id ?

if I try User user = event.getUser() or ((User)event.getUser()).getId()
I get

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException:
 org.springframework.security.authentication.
 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken 
 cannot be cast to com.newcode.meeting.domain.User
```

Comment: `event.getUser().getPrincipal();` or `((MyUserClass)event.getUser()).getId();`

Comment: ((User) event.getUser()).getId())                                                                                       java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to com.newcode.meeting.domain.User

Comment: `((User)event.getUser().getPrincipal()).getid();`

Comment: wrong .getPrincipal() -- "Cannot find declaration to go to"                                  Principal  pr = event.getUser()

Comment: This is the implementation of the toString() method on UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken you are currently printing. So i'm sure you can work it out: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(super.toString()).append(": ");
  sb.append("Principal: ").append(this.getPrincipal()).append("; ");
  sb.append("Credentials: [PROTECTED]; ");
  sb.append("Authenticated: ").append(this.isAuthenticated()).append("; ");
  sb.append("Details: ").append(this.getDetails()).append("; ");`

Comment: is there any more elegant solution ??

Comment: Given the above I am sure the last solution should work. Given that `Principal pr = event.getUser()` corresponds with teh API docs I dont see how that can be wrong. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/AbstractSubProtocolEvent.html#getUser--

Answer (score 0):

I found only one way to get the user
since "event.getUser ()" we get "Principal" =>

```
  User connection : 
  org.springframework.security.authentication.Usernam 
  ePasswordAuthenticationToken@fe260c00: Principal: 
  User(id=1, username=admin, 
  password=$2a$08$VDogbqVQY23gNnLFty/6ReGLecW/bk3oCkUHrsly4HgjBIGRNBSEC, 
  email=kiy9@gmail.com); Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: 
  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: 
  RemoteIpAddress: 
  0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3566D00689DCC01041367983F3132937; Granted Authorities: USER
```

and there is only one method "getName" but it doesn’t suit us,because our name is not unique and  turn "Principal" to "User" is impossible and we use work with String)

```
@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
    logger.info("Received a new web socket connection:=> "event.getUser().getName());
    User user = userRepo.findUserById(getUserId(event.getUser()));
   // code
}
private Long getUserId(Principal principal) {
    String userString = principal.toString();
    int startIndex = userString.indexOf("id=");
    int endIndex = userString.indexOf(",", startIndex);
    return Long.valueOf(userString.substring(startIndex + 3, endIndex));
}
```

Not very elegant but works))

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrieve the User from the object you receive.

> if I try User user = event.getUser() or ((User)event.getUser()).getId() I get...

`event.getUser()` method returns object of the Principal type which does not belong to the User class hierarchy so you can't simply cast it to this class.
Despite the method's return type the actual object that you receive is an instance of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

Principal type does not allow to retrieve User from the object, but casting `event.getUser()` to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` or its superclass - `Authentication` will do the trick:

Instead of:

```
User user = (User) event.getUser();
```

call:

```
User user = (User) ((Authentication) event.getUser()).getPrincipal();
```